# ImportError: cannot import name Eog, introspection typelib not found

Tags: apt, gnome, python, gtk

I am trying to get the eye of the gnome plugin demo working from [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome/Plugins). I have installed the dependencies, but on the line `from gi.repository import GObject, Eog`, `Eog` cannot be found.
If I go to the `gi.repository` directory with : `ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/`, I can see:

```
Dee.py                 GObject.py  Gio.py   Pango.py     __pycache__
GIMarshallingTests.py  Gdk.py      Gtk.py   Unity.py     keysyms.py
GLib.py                Gedit.py    IBus.py  __init__.py
```

But no `Eog.py`. What package will install this file?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert Bionic. I was going to try live boot trusty or xenial, whichever the tutorial was wriiten for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems that path of `Eog-3.0.typelib` on 18.04 LTS was wrong.

So I created symbolic link to move it one level higher:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/eog/girepository-1.0/Eog-3.0.typelib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Eog-3.0.typelib
```

And then I can run `python3 -c "from gi.repository import Eog"`.

---

Also I have found "fallback" method.

We can install `eog-plugin-python-console` and use it as development console:

```
sudo apt install eog-plugin-python-console
```

Then enable it in Eye of GNOME *Preferences → Plugins* and launch from menu by clicking on *Python Console*:

[image: Python Console inside Eog]

I think that you can get the source code of actual Eog plugins with `apt-get source eog-plugins` and then try to read and/or change it.